# I'm not able to center these buttons

Tags: css, alignment

The wrapper is of width 100% and here is the screeenshot. I have defined the width of container of buttons and set the margin to auto but no luck.

[image: 'image']

I have also tried inline-block on the div of buttons.

Comment: `margin-left= calc(50% -132px)`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you don't have a `float: left;` instruction on the div where the buttons are contained.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
margin:0 auto;
```

to your buttons class.

Comment: I have done that already. Maybe I have to add another div just forr the buttons that takes up the whole width and buttons class then will be center aligned in that.. Say what?

Comment: put margin left to the button container in percentage.

Comment: I tried inline-block on buttons anchors and it worked like a charm. Plus I had float:left on every element. I removed that.

Comment: @UmerJaved Please remove width from button's parent div or make it 100%. & use margin:0 auto; to buttons as suggested by Rene.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your buttons be inheriting the `style` property of some parent.

you can try overriding the `float` property set by the parent or the default `class`.

The problem with your code is that the `CSS/sass` is under `@media` queries (for example when the screen width is smaller). and you are applying to the `div` without the `@media` queries, so your `styles` are not getting applied.

Try looking for such media queries in your code.. this could become really easy in chrome when inspecting a tag see the top most `css` being applied and add some changes to it, in your current case you can simply try.

```
float: none
```

or

```
float: initial
```

after the changes work you could update them inside your actual file finding where to update is really easy. just look at the top right of the block you updated it'll have a link to file and the line number of the block. go and update your changes within that file.

Hope this helps.